# Terraform Data Pipeline Creation

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, aws-cloudformation, amazon-data-pipeline

I am running Terraform version 0.12.18 and AWS version 2.43.0. What I am trying to do is create a data pipeline in terraform to perform backups from EFS into S3 buckets. In Terraform, I am creating my data pipeline with a cloudformation stack. When executing Terraform, it is failing on the part of creating this pipeline. The error message I am getting is below:

[image]

This is also the part of my pipeline script that is executing:

```
  - Id: ShellCommandActivityObj
      Name: ShellCommandActivityObj
      Fields:
        - Key: type
          StringValue: ShellCommandActivity
        - Key: runsOn
          RefValue: EC2ResourceObj
        - Key: command
          StringValue: |
            source="$1"
            region="$2"
            destination="$3"
            sudo yum -y install nfs-utils
            [[ -d /backup ]] || sudo mkdir /backup
            if ! mount -l -t nfs4 | grep -qF $source; then
              sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1 -o rsize=1048576 -o wsize=1048576 -o timeo=600 -o retrans=2 -o hard "$source" /backup
            fi
            sudo aws s3 sync --delete --exact-timestamps /backup/ s3://$destination/
            backup_status="$?"
            if [ "backup_status" -eq "2"]; then
              backup_status="0"
            fi
            exit "$backup_status"
        - Key: scriptArgument
          StringValue: "#{myEFSSource}"
        - Key: scriptArgument
          StringValue: "#{myEFSId}"
        - Key: scriptArgument
          StringValue: "#{myRegion}"
        - Key: scriptArgument
          StringValue: "#{myS3BackupsBucket}"
        - Key: onSuccess
          RefValue: SuccessNotify
        - Key: onFail
          RefValue: FailureNotify
```

Any advice on this error would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like $destination is missing..

Comment: I'm sorry, where do you see it missing?